# Does any version of PhantomJS support javascript generators?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, ecmascript-6

I am using PhantomJS version 1.9.8, and I get an error "SyntaxError: Parse error" on a file that makes use of a generator (supported by javascript 1.7).

I can't find any documentation on what PhantomJS does and does not support, does anyone know of such a document? Or know of a workaround to get PhantomJS to parse function* and for..of statements?

Comment: Phantomjs should support what ever functionality the version of Webkit that it was forked from supports.

Comment: To expand on Nit's comment, PhantomJS 1.x fork is now more than 4 years old and PhantomJS 2 fork more than a year old. PhantomJS 2 is not out yet.

Comment: SlimerJS appears to support them (it has same feature set as a recent Firefox), and might be a drop-in replacement, depending on what exactly you are doing. BTW, as a *rough* guide, Phantom 1.x is the same as Chrome 13.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [PhantomJS 2.0 is based on 7 month old WebKit](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/PhantomJS-2) and considering that even [latest WebKit doesn't support generators yet](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#webkit), I'm pretty sure PhantomJS 2.0 does not support them.

We'll be [adding it to the compat table soon](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/issues/243), so you'll be able to see exact (and up to date) support breakdown.